# c# Task Scheduler, delayed task

Tags: c#, task, scheduler

I'm making this C# application that creates a task that runs the 1st of every month (everithing ok so far) but if the computer is turned off at the time of the trigger, the task is skipped and executed until the next month.

So my question is: is there a way that if the trigger didn't fire then execute another trigger when the computer is turned on again?

here is my code so far:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler; // this is the 2.0 library
namespace TaskSchedulerForDataUsage
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TaskService myTaskService=new TaskService())
        {
            TaskDefinition myTaskDefinition = myTaskService.NewTask();
            myTaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does Something";
            myTaskDefinition.Triggers.Add(new MonthlyTrigger(1,MonthsOfTheYear.AllMonths));

            myTaskDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("Here is a path with a  .exe ",null,null));
            myTaskService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"AwesomeStuff",myTaskDefinition);
            //in case you want to erase the task
            //myTaskService.RootFolder.DeleteTask("AwesomeStuff");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It seems like you're looking for [`TaskSettings.StartWhenAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383524(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, that's what Fercho54's doing. He's trying to use Windows Task Scheduler from C#.

Comment: @NikolayKhil. Doh! Obviously I didn't read the question very well. Thanks.